# Call JS bundle from GoMobile?

Tags: javascript, go, react-native, gomobile

It's my understanding that ReactNative compiles it's JavaScript into a JS bundle available here: http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle

Is it possible within GoMobile to render a view using that JS bundle file?

I'm trying to figure out if I can use Go for backend app development and ReactNative for the UI, without having to hook up bindings to Swift/Java.

Answer (score 0):

That js bundle is/can be used the React Engine that has specific native implementations for both ios and android.

1. One way you could use is if you have a GoMobile implementation/bindings of ReactEngine.
2. Another way as you have already mentioned is by Objective C-Swift/Java bindings.
3. Another way is you could implement a embedded REST API server on GoMobile and use react-native to talk to that.